# TSQL join on possibly empty value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have small stored procedure that is pulling in records. There are currently 2 records in the table. One of them has a value for `A.[managerApproval]` and the other doesn't. Due to the join, if the column doesn't have a value, the whole record doesn't show up rather than just an empty value.

What is a good way to still show the data regardless of if the column its joining on has a value?

```
SELECT A.[id],
       A.[empID],
       A.[firstName],
       A.[lastName],
       A.[emailAddress],
       B.[FirstName] + ' ' +B.[LastName] + ' (' +B.[ntid]+ ')' as managerApproval
FROM   tuitionSubmissions as A
JOIN empTable AS B
ON B.[empID] = A.[managerApproval]
FOR    XML PATH ('data'), TYPE, ELEMENTS, ROOT ('root');
```

Comment: Change your `Join` to `Left Join`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` - it will join the tables on the value if it exists in the second table, otherwise it will return `NULL` for any values you have in your `SELECT` from the second table.

```
SELECT A.[id],
       A.[empID],
       A.[firstName],
       A.[lastName],
       A.[emailAddress],
       B.[FirstName] + ' ' +B.[LastName] + ' (' +B.[ntid]+ ')' as managerApproval
FROM   tuitionSubmissions as A
LEFT OUTER JOIN empTable AS B
ON B.[empID] = A.[managerApproval]
FOR    XML PATH ('data'), TYPE, ELEMENTS, ROOT ('root');
```

For those records, `managerApproval` will be `NULL`

Answer (score 1):

seems like you need a left join:

```
  SELECT A.[id],
       A.[empID],
       A.[firstName],
       A.[lastName],
       A.[emailAddress],
       B.[FirstName] + ' ' +B.[LastName] + ' (' +B.[ntid]+ ')' as managerApproval
    FROM   tuitionSubmissions as A
    Left JOIN empTable AS B
    ON B.[empID] = A.[managerApproval]
   FOR    XML PATH ('data'), TYPE, ELEMENTS, ROOT ('root');
```